# Collapse ContentControl if Content is Collapsed

Tags: wpf, xaml, binding, datatemplate

I've got a ContentControl which has a style containing a border and other visual decorations. I want these decorations to disappear when the content is collapsed, so I figured I have to set the visibility of the ContentControl to collapsed in this case. I got this style for my ContentControl decoration:

```
<Style x:Key="DecoratedItem1" TargetType="{x:Type c:DecoratedItem}">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type c:DecoratedItem}">
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <Border BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="2" CornerRadius="2">
                        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                            <Image Source="/Images/file.png"/>
                            <ContentPresenter Name="wContent"/>
                        </StackPanel>
                    </Border>
                </StackPanel>
                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ElementName=wContent, Path=Content.Visibility}" Value="Collapsed">
                        <DataTrigger.Setters>
                            <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed"/>
                        </DataTrigger.Setters>
                    </DataTrigger>
                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

The DecoratedItem class is just a subclass of ContentControl with additional DependencyProperties which are not relevant to this issue, I just wanted to note that I already have a subclass to which I could add code, if necessary.

This works when the content of the ContentControl is a UIElement, however if the content is generated by a DataTemplate it complains about not being able to find the Visibility property.

```
<!-- works -->
<c:DecoratedItem Style="{StaticResource DecoratedItem1}">
    <TextBlock Text="ABC" Visibility="Collapsed"/>
</c:DecoratedItem>

<!-- doesn't work -->
<c:DecoratedItem Style="{StaticResource DecoratedItem1}" Content="ABC">
    <c:DecoratedItem.Resources>
        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type clr:String}">
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding}" Visibility="Collapsed"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </c:DecoratedItem.Resources>
</c:DecoratedItem>
```

The error for the second case diplayed in the debug output window is:

```
System.Windows.Data Error: 40 : BindingExpression path error:
'Visibility' property not found on 'object' ''String' (HashCode=-885832486)'.
BindingExpression:Path=Content.Visibility;
DataItem='ContentPresenter' (Name='wContent');
target element is 'DecoratedItem' (Name='');
target property is 'NoTarget' (type 'Object')
```

I understand why this happens, but don't know how to fix my style to work as I want it. I don't mind adding helper code to the DecoratedItem subclass if necessary. Any idea how to fix this?

**[edit 1]**

Some more explanation in regard to the proposed answer:

I can't enforce that the Content is always an UIElement. This is a model-view design after all, and of course I simplified the example a lot. In the real project the content is a model selected from the DataContext, which can be of several different types, and the DataTemplate builds a presentation for that model. Some of the DataTemplates decide (depending on model-state) that there is nothing to present and switch Visibility to Collapsed. I would like to propagate that information to the decorating container. The example above really just presents the problem and not the motivation, sorry.

**[edit 2]**

Not sure how knowing more about the model would help the problem, but here we go. The data in the Content field doesn't have much in common since it can be a lot of things, this DecoratedItem is supposed to be reusable to give a common visual style to items shown on some forms. Content can be stuff like work items whose DataTemplate collapses them if they are disabled; other kinds of Content can be incomplete and get collapsed. Of course other kinds never may get collapsed.

But note that the data model doesn't really have much to do with the question, which still is how to bind against the Visibility of the expanded content element (after possibly exposing it through the subclass in a bindable way).

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of ways of describing what's wrong.  In the first, working example:

```
<c:DecoratedItem Style="{StaticResource DecoratedItem1}">
    <TextBlock Text="ABC" Visibility="Collapsed"/>
</c:DecoratedItem>
```

the Content property of the ContentControl is set to be a TextBlock, which is a UIElement with a Visibility property.  (This assumes that you have not changed the ContentPropertyAttribute of your derived class DecoratedItem to be something other than Content).  Thus, your DataTrigger binding can correctly evaluate:

```
 <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ElementName=wContent, Path=Content.Visibility}" Value="Collapsed">
```

Contrast the working case with the failing one:

```
<c:DecoratedItem Style="{StaticResource DecoratedItem1}" Content="ABC">
```

in which the Content property is set to an instance of a String, which does not have a Visibility property.

The other way to describe what's wrong is to note that, even though you supply a DataTemplate for the case of Content being a String, Content is still a String and still does not have a Visibility property.  In other words, the statement that the Content is *generated* by the DataTemplate is incorrect -- your DataTemplate just told the control how to display Content of type String.

The general answer to your question is that, if you want the DataTrigger in DecoratedItem1 bound with a Path of Content.Visibility, you need to make sure the content you put in it is always a UIElement.  Conversely, if you want to be able to put any sort of Content into the control, you need to trigger off of something else.

The specific answer to your question, strictly, relies on your broader intent (in particular, on how the Visibility of the Content of your control will be set/modified).  A couple of possibilities:

- if you really want your DataTrigger binding of the form, "Content.Visibility", make sure that the Content is always a UIElement.  For instance, use the working form of the style and then bind the Text of TextBlock to something appropriate.  However, this doesn't fit so well with the idea of your derived control as a ContentControl, so...
- your DataTrigger could probably bind to something else.  It seems like, from the way the question is formed, that there is some other property or code-behind that will control whether the various content entities are Visible or not.
- finally, you could add an additional DataTrigger to the TextBlock.  This DataTrigger would set the visibility of its parent based on its own visibility.  Then, bind the DataTrigger in style DecoratedItem1 with Path "Visibility" instead of "Content.Visibility", essentially chaining together Visibilities manually.

**Edit**

Based on what you've described about how you want to use this, it sounds like you need to consider the [visual tree](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms753391.aspx#two_trees).  You might augment your DecoratedItem control to have the following functionality:  if all its visual children that are UIElments have a visibility of Collapsed (or if it has no visual children), it is also Collapsed (or, whatever logic makes sense for the desired functionality in terms of the Visibility of its visual children).  You'd need to use the [VisualTreeHelper](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.visualtreehelper.aspx) class from code -- in particular, the GetChildrenCount and GetChild methods.  You'd also, in your DecoratedItem class, override OnVisualChildrenChanged (while still calling the base class method) so that you can get UIElement.IsVisibleChanged events for the visible children.

Comment: Thats a good explanation of what's wrong, but that wasn't the point of the question, sorry if that wasn't clear enough. The question is how to work around the problem, or how to get to the expanded UIElement of the Content. I can't bind to something else because I got multiple DataTemplates, depending on the DataContext (it's a model-view design after all). Visibility of the content is set from some of the DataTemplates. I somehow need to propagate that info to the decorating container.

Comment: So for your suggestions:
1) Not possible because I'm using a model-view design and need the DataTemplate to expand my models.
2) I don't see how I could do that when I have more than one DataTemplate to support different model types. In fact I've chosen the Content-Visibility to be the "common" point to bind against because my models are so different.
3) Not sure I understand that one, need to think more about it.

Comment: If I got it right, (3) would set the Visibility of the ContentPresenter, and then I could bind to that instead of the expanded content. That should probably work, I'll try it out.

Comment: The point is that you still have to have _some_ thing off of which the DataTrigger can trigger.

from your edit:  "Some of the DataTemplates decide (depending on model-state) that there is nothing to present and switch Visibility to Collapsed."

can you expend on that?

Comment: Here you go, more details. Still the data model is not really part of the question, if it's possible to keep it out ;) -- Anyways, I'll accept a workaround like suggestion #3 if it works and no better answer can be found (still need to test it though, will do so tomorrow, didn't have the time today, sorry).

Comment: I'm afraid #3 didn't work out. How do you set the Visibility of a parent from inside a DataTemplate Setter, is that possible at all?